# Не могу найти ошибку в коде с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, арифметика

[image: Нужно вычислить значение функции]

Мой код::

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    
int x, y;
    
    cout << "Введите любой x =";
    
    cin >> x;
    
    cout << endl;
    
    y = ((x-2) / (pow(x, 2/7) + pow(x, 4/3) * pow(2, 1/5) + pow(4 * x, 1/4))) - ((pow(x, 2) - pow(4 * x, 1/2)) / (log10(pow(x, 2/3) + pow(x, 1/3) * pow(24, 1/6))));
    
    cout << "y=" << y;

    return 0;
}
```

Программа выдает при x = 10, y = -328
Калькулятор выдает при x = 10, y = -101

Answer (score 4):

Стандартная ошибка начинающего...

Целое, деленное на целое, дает в С/С++ целое и степени типа `2/7` получаются равными 0.

Делите как `2./7`.

Answer (score 1):

Вычислите сначала 1 часть на калькуляторе(до минуса) - затем в коде; Если в ней совпадут результаты - все ок. Затем 2 -ю. ну и затем отнимате. В любом из вариантов вы получите где то неверный ответ. Тем самым вы уменьшите область поиска и найдете ответ.
Тем самым вы сможете на практике быстрее находить ошибки)